# Perform segue in asynchronous block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After the user is logged in my app I send his user profile to my server using a POST request and if it's done with success I call a success block to notify my controller and inside I want to perform a segue but the segue is not working, nothing happened.

Here my code of the block :

```
RemoteCallManager   *rcm = [[RemoteCallManager alloc] init];

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:IS_FIRST_LAUNCH])
{
    // Is first launch
    [rcm sendNewUserProfile:self.player andSuccessBlock:^(NSDictionary *result) {

        [[Utils sharedInstance] extractAndSaveSessionDataWithResultFromRequest:result];

        [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setPlayer:self.player];
        [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] archivePlayerObject];
        [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] archiveGameSession];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:IS_FIRST_LAUNCH];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToMenu" sender:self];

    } andErrorBlock:^(NSString *description) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured : %@", description);
    }];
}
else
{
    // Is not first launch
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToMenu" sender:self];
}
```

I tried to call the segue in dispatch_sync without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your app go through the `prepareForSegue:`? Could it be an issue with a background/frontground, since only mainthread can update UI?

Comment: Yes it goes through. It exactly what I thought about the mainthread. It's why I tried to used dispatch_sync to perform the segue in the main thread, but I use

Comment: *but when I use `dispatch_sync(dipsatch_get_main_queue(), ... ` the segue is never performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my error but I don't really understand why. I have a loadingViewController which decides if the first view controller to display is the loginViewController or the menuViewController. After login the loginViewController push to the menuViewController using segue.

Between the loadingVC and the loginVC I had a modal segue and between the loginVC and the menuVC a push segue. If I change the modal to push, it works fine.

I don't understand the reason why my segue is not performed with modal. If somebody has an answer, I'll take it :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

did you switch the main-queue in your `dispatch_sync`? I think you should use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ...` as it seems you do not need to wait for the call to execute.

Comment: Yes I did. If I use : `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToMenu" sender:self];});` it enters in the segue but nothing happened